# How to transfer files from a local Ubuntu machine to a windows EC2 instance hosted in AWS?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have a windows server running in AWS. I want to transfer some files from my local (Linux, Ubuntu) to that instance. But I can not find a way to do so. tried connecting with RDP but the drag and drop is not working in this case. Filezilla also not working. So finally I uploaded the file to my google drive and tried accessing the drive inside ec2 instance via internet explorer, But unfortunately, the connection to google chrome is also not working there any better way to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

A common way to move files between computers is to **upload the files to an Amazon S3 bucket**.

Then, on the target computer, **download the files from the S3 bucket to the local disk**.

This way, you do not need to run any servers or open any additional security access.

You can upload/download to S3 using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Take a look at the `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3 sync` commands.

Answer (score 0):

There are more options.

#### 1. Amazon S3

As another user has suggested, you can use Amazon S3 to upload files from local linux using cli (or web frontend), then on the windows vm, you can download from S3, all secure.

#### 2. Dropbox

If you want to have an automated way of syncing files, you can use maybe Dropbox (files will be synced automatically). Also a secure option.

#### 3. FTP

You must install a FTP Server on the windows vm, then from linux you can use Filezilla to send files.
*NOTE* FTP is not a secure way of sending files, i would not use it on windows anyway. SFTP is a more secure option, but is probably too advanced/complicated and it doesn't make any sense in your case.